# Calling class methods via class name vs self

Tags: objective-c, class-method

Suppose we have a class named `Calculator`. There's a class method in it, called `runProgram`.
If I wanted to call this class method, inside the class's implementation, what would the difference between these two be:

```
[Calculator runProgram]
```

OR

```
[self runProgram]
```

Are these both the same?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If inside an instance method:

```
[self runProgram]
```

in this, `self` means the object instance itself, and thus it will generate a runtime error. You want to use

```
[[self class] runProgram]
```

instead.

However, if you call this method from another class method, then

```
[self runProgram]
```

is correct, since now `self` refers to the class itself. I'd discourage to use

```
[Calculator runProgram]
```

because then subclasses of the class would erroneously call the superclass' (`Calculator`'s) method instead of a possibly overridden method.

Comment: With the caveat that `[Calculator runProgram]` is correct for classes that are explicitly nothing to do with `Calculator`, ala usage of the various factory methods?

Comment: +1: Of course, since there is no other method for them! But OP asked about calling the method in the implementor class itself.