# How can I call a method from ViewController?

Tags: inheritance, methods, swift, delegates, protocols

Is it possible to call a method (written in a Gamescene) from a ViewController in Swift? 
I read about Protocol, delegate or Inheritance but all tutorials I saw don't show this case.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: where is you try to call that method?

Comment: I'm trying to call a timer method from my ViewController. The timer method is written is the GameScene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

in ViewController class

```
#import "Gamescene.h"

Gamescene *obj = [[Gamescene alloc] init];

[Gamescene methodName];
```

and don't forgot to add method name in Gamescene.h file..

**in Swift**

```
class SomeClass {
    class func someTypeMethod() {
    // type method implementation goes here
}
```

}

```
SomeClass.someTypeMethod()
```

you can learn [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html) apple Documentation.

Comment: I code in swift. I saw there isn't import statement. Is there a difference in the code ?

Comment: I tried that : `GameScene.startTimer()` but I have a message error : "missing argument for parameters #1 in call"

Comment: is startTimer() method has any parameter to pass?i mean any input needed to pass in this method?

Answer (score 0):

There's following way you can call a method,

- If a method is in your view controller it self then, you can call it with `self`, check question for help, [How can I call a method in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591969/how-can-i-call-a-method-in-objective-c)

  `[self yourMethodName];`

  If its a class method then, `[ClassName yourMethodName];`
- If your method is from other class, just `#import` that class like `#import "someclass.h"` then same, create a object of that class and call, check this for more help, [Objective C - Call method from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106562/objective-c-call-method-from-another-class)

  `someclass *obj = [[someclass alloc] init];`

  `[obj methodName];`

  If its a class method then `[someclass methodName];` check question for help, [calling class methods objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10369946/calling-class-methods-objective-c)
- with delegate, if you've self delegate for `someclass` then in `someclass` you can call it like this, check question, [How do I create delegates in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c)

  `if(self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector(methodName)]) {`
        `[self.delegate methodName];`
   `}`

  and in your view controller you've to write like this,

  `someclass *obj = [[someclass alloc] init];` 
  obj.delegate = self;

  `- (void)methodName {`
      `//call when delegate calls it.`
  `}`
- Anothe way is with `NSNotificationCenter`, see this question for detail help, [Send and receive messages through NSNotificationCenter in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/send-and-receive-messages-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c)